# Proof the existence of identity element in a group of $n!$ permutations on a set of $n$ elements

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

We know that $n!$ permutations on a set of $n$ elements is a group. A proof of this statement starts by considering a set $S=\lbrace a_1, a_2, ..., a_n\rbrace$ and $S'=\lbrace p:~p~\text{is a permutation on $n$ elements of $S$}\rbrace$. Now, our goal is to show that $S'$ is a group with respect to multiplication of permutations. It is easy to show that $(S', \cdot)$ is closed and associative. We are left to show how identity exists in $S'$? I encountered the following proof, but still confused:
Let $I_a=\begin{pmatrix} 
  & a_1 & a_2 &....a_n \\
  & a_1 & a_2 &....a_n
\end{pmatrix}
\quad$,  $I_b=\begin{pmatrix} 
  & b_1 & b_2 &....b_n \\
  & b_1 & b_2 &....b_n
\end{pmatrix}
\quad$ and  $\alpha=\begin{pmatrix} 
  & a_1 & a_2 &....a_n \\
  &  b_1 & b_2 &....b_n
\end{pmatrix}
\quad$; all these three elements belong to $S'$ and $I_a=I_b$ (since $(a_1~a_2...a_n)=(b_1~b_2...b_n)$). Now, $I_a\cdot \alpha=\begin{pmatrix}  
  & a_1 & a_2 &....a_n \\
  & a_1 & a_2 &....a_n
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}  
  & a_1 & a_2 &....a_n \\
  & b_1 & b_2 &....b_n
\end{pmatrix}
\quad=\alpha.$ Similarly, $\alpha\cdot I_b=\begin{pmatrix}  
  & a_1 & a_2 &....a_n \\
  & b_1 & b_2 &....b_n
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}  
  & b_1 & b_2 &....b_n \\
  & b_1 & b_2 &....b_n
\end{pmatrix}
\quad=\alpha.$

Therefore, $I\alpha=\alpha I=\alpha?$ My confusion is why do we take here only, $\alpha\cdot I_b$, but not $I_b\cdot \alpha$ (the product seems not compatible in this case) or,  $I_a\cdot \alpha$, but not $\alpha\cdot I_a $ (the product seems not compatible in this case). Can some one help me to understand this better or, any simpler proof of this?

Comment: If you have both a left identity and a right identity, then they must be equal.  Suppose $I_\ell$ is a left identity and $I_r$ is a right identity.  Then $I_\ell = I_\ell\cdot I_r = I_r$, the left equality as a result of $I_r$ being a right identity and the right equality as a result of $I_\ell$ being a left identity., so, having shown $I_a$ is a left identity and $I_b$ is a right identity, we know that they are the same and so we can drop the subscript and it follows that $I\alpha=\alpha I=\alpha$ and that $I$ is indeed the identity.

Comment: >"It is easy to show that (S′,⋅) is closed, associative inverse exists in it"<



How do you show an inverse exists without an identity?

Comment: @V.Ch. I meant, once the identity is shown to exist, proving the existence of inverse becomes easy (here, i have just assumed that identity exists). My confusion is in proof of existence of identity.

Comment: @V.Ch. edited my sentence in the post accordingly.

Comment: @JMoravitz Would you kindly post your comment as answer with a bit more elaboration?

Comment: gete, this has been proved here at this site already with more elaboration (but essentially you don't need more than what JMoravitz wrote).